# How to populate this my HashMap/keySet()?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have managed to set up a HashMap that is populated if the keySet() method contains words from my getWordArray method. This works fine and compiles, but the issue in which I am facing is that none of my HashMap.keySet() is populated which it should be. The list of instructions that has been given to me are as follows:

- Use keySet() to retrieve the set of keys (the String part of the mapping). Loop over this set and print out the word and its count.
- Use the getWordSet() method to make complete set of all the words from the WordGroup.
- Loop over the new HashSet to print a complete list of all words with the sum counts from each of the hashmaps.

I'm confused on how I would retrieve the set of keys, loop over the HashMap and then print out the word with its count. Any help on how this would be done is greatly appreciated, thanks. P.s. My code so far:

**WordGroup class**

```
package lab5;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WordGroup {

    String  word;

    // Creates constructor which stores a string value in variable "word" and converts this into lower case using
    // the lower case method.
    public WordGroup(String aString) {

        this.word = aString.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String[] getWordArray() {

        String[] wordArray = word.split("-");
        return wordArray;
    }
    public Set<String> getWordSet(WordGroup secondWordGroup) {

 HashSet<String> newHashSet = new HashSet<>();

for (String word : secondWordGroup.getWordArray())
    newHashSet.add(word);

for (String word : this.getWordArray())
    newHashSet.add(word);
System.out.println(newHashSet);
return newHashSet;

}

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getWordCountsMap() {

        HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String word : this.getWordArray()) {
            if (myHashMap.keySet().contains(word)) {
                myHashMap.put(word, myHashMap.get(word) + 1);
            } else {
                myHashMap.put(word, 1);
            }

        }

        return myHashMap;
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
package QuestionEditor;
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        WordGroup firstWordGroup = new WordGroup("You-can-discover-more-about-a-person-in-an-hour-of-plau-tban-in-a-year-of-conversation");
        WordGroup secondWordGroup = new WordGroup ("When-you-play-play-hard-when-you-work-dont-play-at-all");

        System.out.println("*****First Array list*****");
        String[] firstWordArray =  firstWordGroup.getWordArray();
           for( String word : firstWordArray) { 
              System.out.println(word);
        }
        System.out.println("*****Second Array list*****");
        String[] secondWordArray =  secondWordGroup.getWordArray();
           for( String word : secondWordArray) { 
              System.out.println(word); 
        }


         for (String pp : secondWordGroup.getWordSet(secondWordGroup)) {
         System.out.println(pp);
    }
         System.out.println("swdadwdawd");
         for (String pp : firstWordGroup.getWordSet(firstWordGroup)) {
         System.out.println(pp);
    }
         System.out.println("*************************");
         secondWordGroup.getWordCountsMap();
         System.out.println("*************************");
         secondWordGroup.test();
        }
    }
```

Comment: getWordCountsMap() is working just fine, I'm not sure what you are asking for here ?

Comment: At the moment it doesn't produce anything although it compiles. I have been asked to "Use keySet() to retrieve the set of keys (the String part of the mapping). Loop over this set and print out the word and its count." Bt am unsure about how to go about this.

Comment: It does, I've just debug it and got this:
*************************
{play=3, all=1, at=1, work=1, hard=1, when=2, you=2, dont=1}
*************************
Try Syso secondWordGroup.getWordCountsMap() in your main class

Comment: Ah okay, so my source code is fine at least I know that's not the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, what does Syso mean, what does it do and how to you implement it?

Comment: Print it out by using: System.out.println(getWordsCountMap())